# Attribute Starts With Selector = Attribute Starts With Selector?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to troubleshoot a bug written from another developer, and I do not understand the way the Attribute starts with selector is being used.

Inside a dialog box there are input fields with uniquely set id's.

And then when the user submits, the function is attached like so,

```
$('#dialogform').dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             height: 925,
             width: 1025,
             modal: true,
             buttons: {
                 Submit: function () {
 var JQuerycollection = $('#dialogform').data();
                     if (JQuerycollection.isClosed.val() == "False") {

                         JQuerycollection["msg"] = "Submit";
                         JQuerycollection[$('[id^="ETI"]').prop('id')] = $('[id^="ETI"]').val();
```

and then stringified and sent through ajax to the backend:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ JSONcollection: JQuerycollection, dlgMsg: "Submit" })
```

There are two input elements that start with "ETI" for its ID, ETI_1234 and ETI_1235. When I use the debugger in FireFox, I can see only the first one  is being added as a property (This is the bug), "ETI_1234 = 17"

Referencing the JQuery API: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

From the API, I understand the example and how the selector works when the right side is not using another Selector, but I do not understand how it is being used in the code I am troubleshooting.

Comment: "Where the right side is a string".  It's all a string.  You seem to be confused with the id having numbers in it.  But it's all a string.  Attributes are strings.

Comment: Oh right, I meant a single value on the right side not another selector. I will edit.

Comment: `$('[id^="ETI"]')` will find all elements on the page that have an id that starts with that substring, so it can contain multiple elements, however `prop()` only returns a single value.  So it will return the prop of the first element in it's result stack.  If you want to get the prop value from each of the elements found, you will have to map them.  Or loop over them and add them to the object one at a time.

Comment: So since both sides might have multiple values will they stay in sync when iterated over? I understand the left side will grab the id property for each element with an id that starts with "ETI" but the right side I am having more trouble understanding. What happens when multiple values are found on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add all the elements to the object, you need to change:

```
JQuerycollection[$('[id^="ETI"]').prop('id')] = $('[id^="ETI"]').val();
```

to:

```
$('[id^="ETI"]').each(function(){
  JQuerycollection[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

`$('[id^="ETI"]').prop('id')` will return only a single value as `prop()` only returns a single value.  If the result stack of the selector has multiple elements, it will get only the value of the first result, not all of them.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I was thinking the left side Selector would iterate through each property found like in the example of the API.

Answer (score 1):

The bug here is that `$('[id^="ETI"]')` is a selector that might return more than one item, but when used with methods like `.prop()` or `.val()` will only return the value of the first item of the multiple items.

To fix this, you should iterate through the possible multiple elements `$('[id^="ETI"]')` and then on each to do the value assignment.

Something like:

```
$.each($('[id^="ETI"]'), function(i, el) {
    JQuerycollection[$(el).attr('id')] = $(el).val();
});
```

Comment: Don't use the `$.each()` version of each when dealing with the result of a jQuery selector.  Use the `$().each` version.